# Why won't my generated .sln file open in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm dealing with a fairly large C++ code base. The code base is normally intended to be compiled under Linux, using custom build scripts and makefiles. I'm porting the code into Visual Studio, which as anyone who's used Visual Studio would agree, is a pain to do manually.

My own looking has been kind of fruitless, so I started writing my own utility in Qt to analyze the codebase and generate a solution file and accompanying `.vcxproj` files. I've been using the `QUuid` class to generate GUIDs for each of the projects, and I'm using `QTextStream` to write the `.sln` file.

Now, here's the problem: When I open the generated `.sln` file, I see the following errors.
[image: The selected file is not a valid solution file]
[image: The system can not find the file specified]

I'm currently trying to generate a solution that I've already manually created within the Visual Studio IDE. I've compared my generated `.sln` file against the the one Visual Studio created, and apart from the projects appearing in a different order and the GUIDs not matching (obviously), I can't spot a difference. I'm including a simplifed example of my problem here.

**Visual Studio generated this:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "mylib", "mylib\mylib.vcxproj", "{35BAFEEE-35FA-4313-AF67-AF8AB7458451}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {35BAFEEE-35FA-4313-AF67-AF8AB7458451}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {35BAFEEE-35FA-4313-AF67-AF8AB7458451}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {35BAFEEE-35FA-4313-AF67-AF8AB7458451}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {35BAFEEE-35FA-4313-AF67-AF8AB7458451}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**And I generated this:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "mylib", "mylib\mylib.vcxproj", "{A09FDB84-49CD-4C14-9D7D-D813D2D905EF}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A09FDB84-49CD-4C14-9D7D-D813D2D905EF}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {A09FDB84-49CD-4C14-9D7D-D813D2D905EF}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {A09FDB84-49CD-4C14-9D7D-D813D2D905EF}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {A09FDB84-49CD-4C14-9D7D-D813D2D905EF}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Here are my questions:

1. What do these specifc error messages mean?
2. Is there any way I can get more specific information on what's wrong with the `.sln` file?
3. Is there something wrong with the GUIDs I'm generating? Should I be using the Visual Studio tool to create GUIDs?
4. Is there some metadata or other invisible special sauce in the file that I'm missing?

I'm pretty sure the issue isn't with text encoding--I used notepad to create a UTF-8 version of the `.sln` and tried opening that instead.

In light of everything, it seems like my GUIDs are causing the issue--though I'm not sure how or why.

### Update

The only major difference I noticed between these files was the file size. The two files differ by exactly 3 bytes, but I couldn't see anything in the file using my text editor. However, an article by [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) got me thinking. There ain't no such thing as plain text--everything's just a representation of 1's and 0's, after all.

I opened up the two files in a hex editor, and presto, I found the 3 bytes at the start of the Microsoft-generated file! (`0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF`). These three bytes also appear in a Visual Studio 2008 solution I had lying around on a different machine. I could probably write my code to slip these bytes into the file before I start writing the solution, but that still begs the question:

**What the heck are these bytes for, and why is Microsoft using them?**

Comment: Mabybe line ending style, <LF> vs <CR><LF>?

Comment: I hoped that was it, but the file looks fine in notepad, and KDiff3 reports that it's using DOS line endings. :(

Comment: Can you try using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [PreMake](http://industriousone.com/premake) to generate solution files for Visual Studio. If they open correctly then you can diff yours with these and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Long shot - If you transplant the ms guids from a valid sln file into your generated one does it work?

Comment: @wnraman: That might be an intelligent way to go, since PreMake supports Qt pretty nicely. I might just generate a Lua script, instead. :-P

Comment: @Matt: Good idea. It's a little painful to do that, but it'd help me isolate the problem.

Comment: This is very unproductive and not at all useful to anybody else that may have the same problem.  Companies that forbid sharing simple info need to take care of their own support.

Comment: Point well taken...I'll add some more information to this problem either today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are contemplating is a [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

It is used to indicate that the file is UTF-8 encoded, and it is supposed to be rendered as a blank, zero width space. If you have the choice, please don't use it -- it makes the file more difficult to read with standard text editors.

Opening the file with notepad and saving it as UTF-8 encoded text will add those three bytes for you. But again, don't use the BOM on files which are meant to be portably read.

Comment: Thanks...it didn't occur to me to simply try a Google search with those bytes. The file did indeed work once I saved it using notepad. I'll make sure my application puts the BOM in, but I'll heed your warning...don't use the BOM unless you really, really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Debug Visual Studio with Visual Studio:

Before opening your generated solution with Visual Studio, open another instance of Visual Studio, go to `Debug->Exceptions` and check all the check boxes, then go to `Debug->Attach to Process...` and attach to `devenv.exe`. Now open the solution in the other VS, and you'll get a break and a call stack which might give you more information.

Comment: I'm having a few issues with this. First problem is that my `Debug` menu doesn't include `Exceptions`. When I try doing this, I get no output from the VS opening my file (likely because I'm not catching the exception).

Comment: The functionality is still there, but your GUI settings hid the access. Re enable it [this way](http://www.williamkent.net/archive/2007/09/12/exception-item-missing-from-my-vs2005-debug-menu.aspx).

Comment: Got it, tried it. Still didn't help. Good idea, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer I accepted, in the case of Qt, I made use of the [following method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#setGenerateByteOrderMark) in the `QTextStream` object I was using to write the solution file:

```
void QTextStream::setGenerateByteOrderMark ( bool generate )
```

Syntax is like so:

```
QFile fileHandle("mylib.sln");
QTextStream fileStream(&fileHandle);
// ...file open and error handling goes here...
fileStream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
fileStream << "\nMicrosoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00\n";
//etc, etc
```

This will make sure that your file has the Byte Order Mark, which in this specific case, Visual Studio needs in order to open the file.